# Segmentation Error in C Code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am totally new to C and I am about to write a function that reverses a string. My code looks like this:

```
char *str = "abcdef";
char *ptr;
for(ptr = str; *ptr ; ptr++);

for(; str < --ptr; str++)
{
    char c = *str;
    *str = *ptr;
    *ptr = c;

}
```

I get a segmentation fault error. And I don't see the mistake (maybe it is too obvious). Any hints?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
char *str = "abcdef";
```

to

```
char str[] = "abcdef";
```

The first `str` points to a string literal and string literals are not modifiable in C,

Comment: So internally I can change a String if it is declared as an array of characters but not a string literal?

Comment: You are not allowed to modify a string literal. In the second case, you have an array initialized with the content of a string literal. You can modify this array as it is not a string literal.

Comment: @ouah if char *str is declared as char str[], does it gets stored in the data section of the program?

Comment: @John This is implementation defined as C says nothing about sections, but typically it depends on the scope where `str` is declared. Usually at file scope, `str` would end up in the data section.

Comment: @ouah: How do i verify this ? If you are correct and if char str[] is declared inside a function then for every call it gets intialised to the so and so string. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is stored in ROM, so you can't write to it. Depends on your platform though.

Comment: ROM is read-only memory, but not all read-only memory is ROM.